# timeline view divider not draggable in fullcalendar v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, divider

I can't resize resources and events by divider bar

[image]

I tried to find the property to allow it to resize but it didn't work.
Please let me know if you have done it through fullcalendar.
I thank you very much if you find something about divider.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceAreaWidth may help you

Comment: I tried resourceAreaWidth but it only sets the width of the resource section and I can't resize it using the divider.

Comment: In that case it is not currently possible to do it

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: Thank you for helping me. In the following way, I was able to resize it:
1. Please install npm i @fullcalendar/interaction
2. Add plugin: plugins={[interactionPlugin]} imported from the package installed above
3. set editable attribute: true

Comment: Ah that is good knowledge, so please add it properly as an Answer below, so it can be searched and voted on. Comments are not searchable and your question appears unanswered right now. See also [answer]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following way, I was able to resize it:

1. Please install npm i @fullcalendar/interaction
2. Add plugin: plugins={[interactionPlugin]} imported from the package installed above
3. set editable attribute: true